# Automatically generated images are not found by server and not displayed on web page

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

The user can define configurations via the web page. With these a program is started, which analyzes data and generates graphics. The generated graphics should be displayed on the website after completion.

After the program has run, this error message is displayed in the browser.

[Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3sVh.png)

HTTP404: NOT FOUND: The server has not found a match for the requested Uniform Resource Identifier (URI). GET - http://localhost:8080/images//15.08.2019-101505/0405-DLH401.jpeg

The folder "images" is located under resources/static/images
The folder "15.08.2019-101505" is generated by the program, as is the image name "0405-DLH401.jpeg". Both are generated.

The path to the image is transmitted via Thymeleaf. Various methods have been tried out.

```
<img th:src="${image}"/> //Preferred variant
<img th:src="@{${'images\' + image}}"/> //Just for testing, did not work.
```

For the first variant, Thymeleaf displays this path:

```
<img src="images//15.08.2019-101505\0405-DLH401.jpeg"/>
```

Several paths have been tested with /, //, \, \. The path was still not found.

However, if I use an image that has already been generated, it will be displayed.

One consideration was to define an external resource folder. However, all sources were 3 - 4 years old and I'm not sure if the procedures are up to date.

Whether this is really the solution is questionable. In a video an image was uploaded, saved to resources/static/photos and then displayed on the website.
Link to the Video: [Show image with variable name Thymeleaf Spring Boot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gE-C7xF3Xg)

If you need more information, please ask!
Otherwise many thanks for all possible solutions / tips or hints.

Software used:

Spring Tool Suite Version 3.9.7

Spring Boot Version 2.1.3

**EDIT**

I've found a solution. Apparently there are two directories in STS. Once `resources/static/images` or what ever. So far I thought STS would get the images from this directory. However, these images are only copied to `target/classes/static` If I delete static graphics from this folder that are not generated, they will not be displayed on the website. If I now change the directory by saving the generated graphics to `target/classes/static/folder name/[...]` the generated graphics will be displayed on the website.

Comment: This isn't a thymeleaf problem.  You need to find the actual url to the image, and then the thymeleaf part of it is easy.  I suspect that like many others who try this, that `resources/static` isn't the appropriate place for those images.  You need to place them in a database, or another directory outside your project and create a controller to display the images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can place the generated images into the "static" folder of a Spring Boot app after it has started and expect them to be served.  Hence the name "static"; i.e. you get what you get when the app starts, you cant add to that after the application has started (without effectively reloading the application context).

Why don't you take a look at Spring Content, a community project, that provides  Spring Data like Java and REST API's for content; i.e. files, images, and videos.  It provides two types of Resource storage; one for direct access (via the Spring Resource API) and a second for associating content with Spring Data entities in order to build much richer "content services".  It also provides extension APIs for renditions and full-text indexing.

As you have Spring Boot it is pretty easy to add to your project?

> pom.xml

```
   <!-- other dependencies -->
   ...

   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-fs-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

> StoreConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
public class EnableFilesystemStoresConfig {

    @Bean
    File filesystemRoot() {
        try {
            return new File("/path/to/your/uploaded/files");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {}
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(filesystemRoot().getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

> ImageStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="generatedImages")
public interface ImageStore extends Store<String> {
}
```

This is all you need to do to get REST Endpoints that will allow you to store and retrieve files.  How this actually works is very much like Spring Data.  When your application starts Spring Content will see the `spring-content-fs` dependency, know that you want to store content on your filesystem and inject a filesystem implementation of the `ImageStore` interface into the application context.  It will also see the `spring-content-rest` and inject a controlller (i.e. REST endpoints) that talk to the `ImageStore` interface.  Therefore, you don't have to do any of this yourself.

So, in your case, I would suggest auto wiring the `ImageStore` into your image generator and using the Java API to store the generated image.  Something like:

```
  @Autowired
  private ImageStore images;

  public class ImageGenerator {

    public generate(...some input variables...) {
      InputStream generatedImageInputStream in = generateImage();  
      Resource generatedImage = images.getResource(generatedFilename());    
      IOUtils.copy(generatedImageInputStream, generatedImage.getOutputStream());
    }
```

This will store the image on the filesystem at `/path/to/your/uploaded/files/some-generated-filename.jpg`

And then on the client-side use the REST API as follows:

`<img th:src="/generatedImages/some-generated-filename.jpg"/>`

will fetch it again and so on.  In case it is useful these endpoints support full CRUD and the GET & PUT endpoints also support video streaming (or byte range-requests).

You could also decide to store the contents elsewhere like in the database, or in cloud storgae by swapping the `spring-content-fs` dependency for the appropriate Spring Content Storage module.  Examples for every type of storage are [here](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content-examples).

In addition, in case it is helpful, content is often associated with Spring Data Entities.  So, it is also possible to have the ImageStore interface implement `ContentStore` instead.  If you are interested in this then let me know and I can update the answer.

HTH